# Alpine js how check checkbox on table row click

Tags: alpine.js

I have table with checkox in one of the cell. How check checkbox when table row is clicked?:

```
<tr
    x-data="{id:'items.index'}"
>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" x-bind:value="id" x-model="selected_examinations">
    </td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
</tr>
```

I tried this:

```
<tr
    x-data="{id:'items.index'}"
    @click="
    if (selected_examinations.includes(id)) {
        const index = selected_examinations.indexOf(id);
        selected_examinations.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
        selected_examinations.push(id)
    }"
>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" x-bind:value="id" x-model="selected_examinations">
    </td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
</tr>
```

But when I ckick on checkbox two same indexes appear in selected_examinations array.

Whole component:

```
<div x-data="{ selected_examinations: [] }">


    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >
            <span x-text="selected_examinations"></span>
                {% regroup examination_types by department as department_list %}
                {% for department in department_list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class='text-center'><b>{{ department.grouper }}</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% for examination_type in department.list %}
                    <tr class="clickable-row"
                        x-data="{id:'{{ examination_type.id }}'}"
                        @click="
                        if (selected_examinations.includes(id)) {
                            const index = selected_examinations.indexOf(id);
                            selected_examinations.splice(index, 1)
                        } else {
                            selected_examinations.push(id)
                            total_price += examination_types[id].fields.price
                        }"
                    >
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <input type="checkbox" x-bind:value="id" x-model="selected_examinations">
                            </div>

                        </td>
                        <td>{{ examination_type.name }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <ul>
                            {% for performer in examination_type.performers.all %}
                                <li>{{ performer.full_name }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ examination_type.price }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

variables in {{ }} is the django template tags. I use alpine js to make UI more frendly and intercative

Comment: Could you share the whole component with some example data that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put a `@click` event listener on the `<tr>` element that includes the checkbox itself, then double clicking will happen when you click on the checkbox: first the `<tr>` element's click event fires that adds the selected `id`, then a second one on the checkbox that adds another.

So you should put the `@click` event listener on the second (and subsequent) `<td>` element(s) instead. This prevents the double clicking phenomena.

You can also create a `toggle(id)` method on the main component that ads/removes the respective `id` from the selection list to make the child components more compact.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{selected_examinations: [], 
toggle(id) {
    if (this.selected_examinations.includes(id)) {
        const index = this.selected_examinations.indexOf(id);
        this.selected_examinations.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
        this.selected_examinations.push(id)
    }
}}">
  <table>
    <tr x-data="{id:'1'}">
      <td><input type="checkbox" x-bind:value="id" x-model="selected_examinations" /></td>
      <td @click="toggle(id)">Text #1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr x-data="{id:'2'}">
      <td><input type="checkbox" x-bind:value="id" x-model="selected_examinations" /></td>
      <td @click="toggle(id)">Text #2</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr x-data="{id:'3'}">
      <td><input type="checkbox" x-bind:value="id" x-model="selected_examinations" /></td>
      <td @click="toggle(id)">Text #3</td>
    </tr>    
  </table>

  <div x-text="`Selected items: ${selected_examinations}`"></div>
</div>
```